# Insert phone number stored on SD card into sms send AT command Arduino

Tags: c++, c, arduino, gsm

I am trying to send an SMS message using Arduino UNO and the SIM800L GSM module when a sound level threshold is activated. I have been able to get this done in all aspects except one. I have the telephone number the text message is to be sent to stored in a CONFIG.BAT file on a SD card, the problem I need to resolve is how I can add the number from the SD card into the AT command that specifies the telephone number the SMS is sent to. The code I have so far is below:

The following code is within a function that is called when start device is chosen, the process starts with reading the out put on the A0 pin to identify when a sound exceeds the level set in the threshold int, this then sets the pin 13 to high, then the process initiates the SD card, checks that there is a CONFIG.BAT on the card and if there isn't a CONFIG.BAT file tells the user to go to setup and set a telephone number for alerts. If the CONFIG.BAT does exist then the process goes on to read the contents of the CONFIG.BAT file. The next step is to set the sms to ASCII format, then set the phone number, then the message content.

```
void sound_detect(){

  int sensorValue = analogRead(A0);//use A0 to read the electrical signal

  if(sensorValue > thresholdvalue) {

  digitalWrite(ledPin1,HIGH);//if the value read from A0 is larger than 400,then light the LED
  delay(10);
  digitalWrite(ledPin1,LOW);

 Serial.print("Initializing SD card...");

  pinMode(10, OUTPUT);

  if (!SD.begin(SD_CS_PIN)) {
    Serial.println("initialization failed!");
    return;
  }

  Serial.println("initialization done.");  

  if (!SD.exists("CONFIG.DAT")) {

    Serial.println("No Number Exists! Please go to Setup Device to add Number for Alert");

  }else{

  // open the file for reading:
  myFile = SD.open("CONFIG.DAT");

  if (myFile) {

    Serial.println("CONFIG.DAT:");

    // read from the file until there's nothing else in it:
    while (myFile.available()) {

      Serial.write(myFile.read());

    }

      //Serial.println(myFile);    

    // close the file:
    myFile.close();

  } else {

    // if the file didn't open, print an error:
    Serial.println("error opening CONFIG.DAT");

  }

  }


    //Set SMS format to ASCII
  serialSIM800.write("AT+CMGF=1\r\n");
  delay(1000);

  //Send new SMS command and message number
  serialSIM800.write("AT+CMGS=\"+44*************\"\r\n");
  delay(1000);

  //Send SMS content
  serialSIM800.write("TEST SMS NOISE DETECT");
  delay(1000);

  //Send Ctrl+Z / ESC to denote SMS message is complete
  serialSIM800.write((char)26);
  delay(1000);

  Serial.println("SMS Sent!");


  } 

}
```

I need help or advice on how i get the telephone number from the SD card which is held in the "myFile" variable in this bit of code

```
while (myFile.available()) {

      Serial.write(myFile.read());

    }
```

to replace the phone number in the AT command here

```
  //Send new SMS command and message number
  serialSIM800.write("AT+CMGS=\"+44*************\"\r\n");
```

I have looked at the AT commands to see if there is a clear way to do this to no avail, I tried putting the "myFile" variable within curly brackets {myFile}

```
  //Send new SMS command and message number
  serialSIM800.write("AT+CMGS=\"{myFile}\"\r\n");
```

but that didn't work.

Any help would be most appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Declare a string in loop():

```
String number ="";
```

Concat the character read from file:

```
while (myFile.available()) {

  number.concat(myFile.read());

}
```

Concat number to `AT-comand`:

```
serialSIM800.write("AT+CMGS=\"+44"+number+"\"\r\n");
```

That's the idea but could you do it in many ways.

Comment: I have tried this now and get the error no matching function for call to `'SoftwareSerial::write(StringSumHelper&)'`                                                on line of code                                     `serialSIM800.write("AT+CMGS=\"+44"+number+"\"\r\n");`

Comment: You could send something if you hardcode the number? I mean, if you coment the part of file reading and write the AT command in code. I write this answer expecting that you had make some unitary test.

Comment: I had the telephone number hard coded and when the threshold was exceeded the sms was sent, with the code you offered I can see the number is represented in char (each number is represented by its ascii code although from what I can tell there is an addition on the end of the code that isnt part of the phone number), so by using `Serial.println(number);` I can see the ascii number.  I have been trying to figure out how to write the AT code so it will read the ascii code and automatically read it as the telephone number but I havent been able to understand or identify that process as yet.

Comment: Following is the AT code I use for the sending of the smds,     following is the AT code I use for the sending of the smd:  `//Set SMS format to ASCII
  serialSIM800.write("AT+CMGF=1\r\n");
  delay(1000);
 
  //Send new SMS command and message number
  serialSIM800.write("AT+CMGS=\"+44"+number+"\"\r\n");
  delay(1000);
   
  //Send SMS content
  serialSIM800.write("TEST SMS NOISE DETECT");
  delay(1000);
   
  //Send Ctrl+Z / ESC to denote SMS message is complete
  serialSIM800.write((char)26);
  delay(1000);
     
  Serial.println("SMS Sent!");`